# How to set cron from Controller (Laravel 5 )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, automation

Is it impossible to create a Cronjob **from** Controller with Laravel 5 Scheduler?

As I know, Laravel Scheduler can work with cron's but only in App\Console\Kernel classes.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
 {
     $schedule->call(function () {
         DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
     })->daily();
 }
```

Maybe is it possible to call alike function from route dynamical and with arguments?

I need to set cronjobs for Home Automation project (light switch on/of; remote control commands e.t.c). Maybe the Idea to execute command with sleep direct to terminal is good too?

Maybe someone have other effective ideas to do it?

Comment: Perhaps a service layer would work for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Laravel Queues. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues